# How To Handle Homonyms

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am in the process of creating an agent that will handle call requests via speech. For example, here is what the flow looks like:

1). User says: **I need to call John**

2). The agent grabs **John** as the parameter and via fulfillment it queries a database for all the entries that contains **John** in a certain field. If there is more than one John, a follow up intent is triggered and sends a response asking which John is the desired one:

Agent says: **There are several Johns, who do you wish to call? John Test, John Smith, John Pleis or John Schmidt?**.

3). The user wants to get in touch with **John Pleis**.

User says: **John Pleis**

Here is where I'm having problem. Dialogflow is recognizing **John Please**, instead of **John Pleis**. How can I handle this?

### Update

Here is how the intent looks:

**-- INITIAL INTENT --**

[image: Initial intent]

[image: Initial intent]

**-- FOLLOW UP INTENT --**

[image: Follow up intent]

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55577397/edit) your question to include screen shots of the Intents that you're currently using to capture the user saying the name (for example, when they say "John Pleis")?

Comment: @Prisoner I've update the question with the info you were requesting. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to address these by using your own [Entity Types](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities) for the names instead of using the [System Entity Type](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/system-entities) of `@sys:any`. This lets you specify the possible names that would be accepted and Dialogflow can work with the assistant to better understand what the user might be saying. This isn't perfect, but can improve phrase detection, and can provide you with some tools to help it out to make detection even better.

If your directory is relatively small (a few hundred people, perhaps), you can simply create [Developer Entity Types](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities) up front for all the names. (There is even [an API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.entityTypes/patch) for managing these Entity Types, so you can automate it.)

If you have too many names, you may want to just create Developer Entity Types for the possible first names (or use the System Entity Type of `@sys:given-name` if that is suitable enough) and then, as part of your fulfillment webhook, populate a [Session Entity Type](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/session-entities) with the possible names that match.

In either of these cases, you can also use entity aliases to help improve matching. So if you see that "John Please" is still matching, then you can set this up as an alias for "John Piels" and Dialogflow will report this as "John Piels" for that Entity.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'll do some testing and update you with the results. Thanks.

Comment: Although this works, the phone database have over 1500 entries with both first and last names. Having to maintain this on the entities section is not what I was looking for; Nevertheless, is the best option so far. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a link to the API for updating entities, so you can automate this as well.